# How to keep cell border with a column background color?

Tags: tables, colortbl

I used my [score board](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367891/is-there-a-better-way-for-drawing-my-table) for a while now, but it appears that it's hard to know in which column I need to write.

So my idea was to color every other column so I know which one I need to use.

Here is what I got so far:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{14pt}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}

\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}X}

\newcommand\customTable{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cc|c|X|g|G|c|X|g|G|c|X|g|G|c|X|g|G|c|X|g|G|c|c|}
        \cline{3-22}

        & & \multicolumn{20}{ c| }{\LARGE Joueurs} \\ \cline{3-22}

        & & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{} \\ \cline{1-24}

        \customRow{10}{\multirow{20}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\LARGE Cartes}}}\cline{2-24}
        \customRow{9}{}\cline{2-24}
        \customRow{8}{}\cline{2-24}
        \customRow{7}{}\cline{2-24}
        \customRow{6}{}\cline{2-24}
        \customRow{5}{}\cline{2-24}
        \customRow{4}{}\cline{2-24}
        \customRow{3}{}\cline{2-24}
        \customRow{2}{}\cline{2-24}
        \customRow{1}{}\cline{1-22}
    \end{tabularx}
}

\newcommand\customHeader[2]{
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{#2} &
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\LARGE #1}}
}

\newcommand\emptyCells{
    & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & ~~~ \\
}

\newcommand\customBorder{
    \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7} \cline{9-9} \cline{11-11} \cline{13-13} \cline{15-15} \cline{17-17} \cline{19-19} \cline{21-21} \cline{23-24}
}

\newcommand\emptyDoubleCells{
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{g|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{g|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{g|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{g|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{g|}{} \\
}

\newcommand\customRow[2]{
    \customHeader{#1}{#2}\emptyCells\customBorder\emptyDoubleCells
}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \customTable
    \customTable
\end{document}
```

Now, every other column have a background but I've lost the borders on those.

I've looked [here](http://texblog.org/2011/04/19/highlight-table-rowscolumns-with-color/) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94799/how-do-i-color-table-columns) for inspiration, but I cannot spot where is my mistake.

So how do I color the background and keep the borders at the same time?

Comment: Why `letter` as document class?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer no reason. What do you suggest?

Comment: `article`? Unless you're writing a letter, of course. Are the borders there when you zoom in? `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` is recommended, by the way.

Comment: I found why I use ```letter```. It's for the margins. I don't see borders while zooming in.

Comment: @A.D. Use the `geometry` package in order to change margins etc. The `letter` class is meant for, you guess it, letters and their special typography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick in case of problems with lines in coloured tables consists in using `hhline`, so I redefined `\customBorder`. Note the very thin white lines in the coloured cells seem to come from the viewer.

*Some explanations on the code*:

An `\hhline` is described by a succession of symbols (one  per column): either `~` (no rule in the corresponding column), or `-` (a single rule) or `=` (a double rule) These symbols can be separated by symbols describing how horizontal rule and vertical rule intersect (`|`, `||` and `:`). Furthermore, if a motto is repeated several times, a short syntax similar to the  `array` package syntax for repeated column type can be used. Here, I used `*{5}{...}`, which means the same motto is repeated 4 times (and used 5!). Also the syntax `>{...}` allows to insert code before the following segment (e.g.  to change the rule colour from the next segment).

To delete white rules in coloured cells, I replaced `~`  which would have been used if the cell were not coloured, with a rule segment of the same colour as the cell, like this `|>{\arrayrulecolor{Gray}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}|- ...`.

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, booktabs}
\newcommand\mycline{\hhline{|~*{23}{|-}}}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{14pt}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}

\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}X}

\newcommand\customTable{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cc|*{5}{c|X|g|G|}c|c|}
        \cline{3-22}

        & & \multicolumn{20}{ c| }{\LARGE Joueurs} \\ \cline{3-22}

        & & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{} & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{} \\ %\cline{1-24}
\hhline{*{24}{-}}

        \customRow{10}{\multirow{20}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\LARGE Cartes}}}%\cline{2-24}
\mycline
        \customRow{9}{}\mycline
        \customRow{8}{}\mycline
        \customRow{7}{}\mycline
        \customRow{6}{}\mycline
        \customRow{5}{}\mycline
        \customRow{4}{}\mycline
        \customRow{3}{}\mycline
        \customRow{2}{}\mycline
        \customRow{1}{}\cline{1-22}
    \end{tabularx}
}

\newcommand\customHeader[2]{
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{#2} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\LARGE #1}}
}

\newcommand\emptyCells{
    & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & ~~~ \\
}

\newcommand\customBorder{%
\hhline{|~|~|*{5}{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-~|->{\arrayrulecolor{Gray}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}--}
}%

\newcommand\emptyDoubleCells{
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{g|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{g|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{g|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{g|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{g|}{} \\
}

\newcommand\customRow[2]{
    \customHeader{#1}{#2}\emptyCells\customBorder\emptyDoubleCells
}

\begin{document}

    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \customTable
    \customTable

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're the man. I've seen about hhline but wasn't sure how to use it. Could you add some explanations on how it works?

Comment: I'll add some words, but you should take a look at the (rather short) documentation of `hhline` and also of `colortbl`, more specifically § 9, `More fun with hhline`.

Comment: Wow! great explanation

Answer (score 1):

I learned how to deal with the annoying effect of white lines in colored cells using the technique explained in the comment of
Ulrike Fischer in
[hhline and cell color problems revisited](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355974/hhline-and-cell-color-problems-revisited)

It is only necessary to raise the line a little.

In the above code, replace

```
\newcommand\emptyCells{
    & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & ~~~ \\
}
```

with

```
    \newcommand\emptyCells{
    & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & & ~~~ & ~~~ \\[-0.5pt] % small shift up <<<<<<<<
}
```

It may just be a PDF viewer effect, but you never know what will come out of a digital press.

Original output
[image: original]

With the modified code
[image: no white lines!]