# How can I automatically convert a table made in MS Word to LaTeX?

Tags: tables, pdftex, msword, convert, word-to-latex

I made the following table with MS Word and I would like to find a tool (online or by command line) on MacOS or Linux to convert it to a LaTeX table:

[image: Table to convert]

As you can see, it is pretty complicated to make this table in LaTeX from scratch. That's why I wonder if someon knows existing tools (online or from the command line) to produce the same table but with a LaTeX source that I could compile to get the same rendering? For the moment, I tried a few online ones on the web but the rendering is very bad.

**UPDATE 1:** Thanks all for your different answers. My issue seems to be more difficult than I thought. I tried to use the converter online:

[Aspose converter PDF TO LATEX](https://products.aspose.app/pdf/conversion/pdf-to-tex)

The rendering is pretty good after a call to PdfLaTeX but the LaTeX source itself can't be processed, there are too many fine-tuned functions and the content itself (made of number of numbers) as well as the text is simply inexploitable, i.e. I can't modify it whitout changing all the format and the rendering of the table.

Here is an example of the beginning of the LaTeX source generated by this online converter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color,pxfonts,fix-cm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{32}{$\ $}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8801}{$\equiv$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{58}{$\colon$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{963}{$\sigma$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{46}{\textperiodcentered}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{60}{\textless}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8226}{$\bullet$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{171}{\guillemotleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{187}{\guillemotright}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[margin=0in,paperwidth=595pt,paperheight=841pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{color_29791}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{color_280669}{rgb}{1,0.705882,0.952941}
\definecolor{color_209140}{rgb}{0.705882,0.776471,0.905882}
\definecolor{color_208148}{rgb}{0.701961,0.772549,0.905882}
\definecolor{color_274846}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{color_283006}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\definecolor{color_282974}{rgb}{1,0.996078,0.996078}
\definecolor{color_280637}{rgb}{1,0.701961,0.94902}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]\path(0pt,0pt);\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{picture}(-5,0)(2.5,0)
\put(56.03423,-71.84601){\fontsize{12}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(473.5844,-71.84601){\fontsize{12}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(56.03423,-85.76599){\fontsize{12}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(473.5844,-85.76599){\fontsize{12}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(56.03423,-99.44604){\fontsize{12}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(473.5844,-99.44604){\fontsize{12}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(56.03423,-113.366){\fontsize{12}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(473.5844,-113.366){\fontsize{12}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(480.8331,-113.366){\fontsize{12}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\end{picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path(0pt,0pt);
\begin{scope}
\clip
(91pt, -707pt) -- (474pt, -707pt)
 -- (474pt, -707pt)
 -- (474pt, 1pt)
 -- (474pt, 1pt)
 -- (91pt, 1pt) -- cycle
;
\filldraw[color_280669][nonzero rule]
(99.2343pt, 0.633972pt) -- (198.1143pt, 0.633972pt)
 -- (198.1143pt, 0.633972pt)
 -- (198.1143pt, -177.206pt)
 -- (198.1143pt, -177.206pt)
 -- (99.2343pt, -177.206pt) -- cycle
;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip
(99pt, -178pt) -- (199pt, -178pt)
 -- (199pt, -178pt)
 -- (199pt, 1pt)
 -- (199pt, 1pt)
 -- (99pt, 1pt) -- cycle
;
\filldraw[color_280669][nonzero rule]
(104.5143pt, -83.84601pt) -- (193.0743pt, -83.84601pt)
 -- (193.0743pt, -83.84601pt)
 -- (193.0743pt, -92.72601pt)
 -- (193.0743pt, -92.72601pt)
 -- (104.5143pt, -92.72601pt) -- cycle
;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{picture}(-5,0)(2.5,0)
\put(104.5142,-91.04602){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}?}
\end{picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path(0pt,0pt);
\begin{scope}
\clip
(91pt, -707pt) -- (474pt, -707pt)
 -- (474pt, -707pt)
 -- (474pt, 1pt)
 -- (474pt, 1pt)
 -- (91pt, 1pt) -- cycle
;
\filldraw[color_209140][nonzero rule]
(198.8343pt, 0.633972pt) -- (466.1943pt, 0.633972pt)
 -- (466.1943pt, 0.633972pt)
 -- (466.1943pt, -92.00598pt)
 -- (466.1943pt, -92.00598pt)
 -- (198.8343pt, -92.00598pt) -- cycle
;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip
(198pt, -93pt) -- (467pt, -93pt)
 -- (467pt, -93pt)
 -- (467pt, 1pt)
 -- (467pt, 1pt)
 -- (198pt, 1pt) -- cycle
;
\filldraw[color_209140][nonzero rule]
(203.8743pt, 0.633972pt) -- (460.9143pt, 0.633972pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, 0.633972pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -8.966003pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -8.966003pt)
 -- (203.8743pt, -8.966003pt) -- cycle
;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{picture}(-5,0)(2.5,0)
\put(221.8743,-6.80603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\end{picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path(0pt,0pt);
\begin{scope}
\clip
(198pt, -93pt) -- (467pt, -93pt)
 -- (467pt, -93pt)
 -- (467pt, 1pt)
 -- (467pt, 1pt)
 -- (198pt, 1pt) -- cycle
;
\filldraw[color_208148][nonzero rule]
(203.8743pt, -8.966003pt) -- (460.9143pt, -8.966003pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -8.966003pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -17.60602pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -17.60602pt)
 -- (203.8743pt, -17.60602pt) -- cycle
;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{picture}(-5,0)(2.5,0)
\put(203.8743,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}Ge}
\put(213.0344,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}n}
\put(217.2016,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}e}
\put(220.528,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}r}
\put(223.8544,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}a}
\put(227.6049,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}l}
\put(229.6889,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(231.5645,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}Ou}
\put(241.5654,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}t}
\put(244.0659,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}p}
\put(248.2331,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}u}
\put(252.4003,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}t}
\put(254.9008,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(256.7765,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}F}
\put(261.3603,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}o}
\put(265.1107,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}r}
\put(268.4372,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}m}
\put(274.6875,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}a}
\put(278.438,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}t}
\put(280.9469,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(282.8221,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}: }
\put(287.1923,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(289.065,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}(a}
\put(295.3101,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}/}
\put(297.3911,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}b}
\put(301.5627,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}) }
\put(305.9329,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}(c}
\put(311.7614,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}/}
\put(313.8423,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}d}
\put(318.0139,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}) }
\put(322.3985,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}[e}
\put(328.227,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791},}
\put(330.0997,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}f]}
\put(335.095,-15.92603){\fontsize{7.44}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\end{picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path(0pt,0pt);
\begin{scope}
\clip
(198pt, -93pt) -- (467pt, -93pt)
 -- (467pt, -93pt)
 -- (467pt, 1pt)
 -- (467pt, 1pt)
 -- (198pt, 1pt) -- cycle
;
\filldraw[color_208148][nonzero rule]
(203.8743pt, -17.60602pt) -- (460.9143pt, -17.60602pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -17.60602pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -26.966pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -26.966pt)
 -- (203.8743pt, -26.966pt) -- cycle
;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{picture}(-5,0)(2.5,0)
\put(332.4243,-25.04602){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\end{picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path(0pt,0pt);
\begin{scope}
\clip
(198pt, -93pt) -- (467pt, -93pt)
 -- (467pt, -93pt)
 -- (467pt, 1pt)
 -- (467pt, 1pt)
 -- (198pt, 1pt) -- cycle
;
\filldraw[color_208148][nonzero rule]
(203.8743pt, -26.966pt) -- (460.9143pt, -26.966pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -26.966pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -36.32599pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -36.32599pt)
 -- (203.8743pt, -36.32599pt) -- cycle
;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{picture}(-5,0)(2.5,0)
\put(203.8743,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}1)}
\put(210.5366,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(212.5384,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}Fi}
\put(219.6505,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}r}
\put(223.1987,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}s}
\put(226.3112,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}t}
\put(228.9724,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(230.9682,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}c}
\put(234.5163,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}o}
\put(238.5159,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}upl}
\put(249.6436,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}e}
\put(253.1917,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(255.1876,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}o}
\put(259.1872,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}f}
\put(261.8483,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(263.8441,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}v}
\put(267.8438,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}a}
\put(271.8434,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}l}
\put(274.0689,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}ue}
\put(282.0681,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}s}
\put(285.1985,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(287.1985,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}: }
\put(291.8618,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}W}
\put(299.8641,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}i}
\put(302.0849,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}th}
\put(309.1955,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}o}
\put(313.1982,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}u}
\put(317.6445,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}t }
\put(322.3119,-34.50952){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}ï¿½}
\put(326.5189,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}?}
\put(328.2805,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}â¡}
\put(334.2572,-34.50952){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}?}
\put(336.0229,-34.50952){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}(a}
\put(343.257,-34.50952){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}?}
\put(345.0208,-34.50952){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}/}
\put(348.9467,-34.50952){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}?}
\put(350.7105,-34.50952){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}b}
\put(355.0958,-34.50952){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791})}
\put(358.4211,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(360.4213,-34.646){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\end{picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path(0pt,0pt);
\begin{scope}
\clip
(198pt, -93pt) -- (467pt, -93pt)
 -- (467pt, -93pt)
 -- (467pt, 1pt)
 -- (467pt, 1pt)
 -- (198pt, 1pt) -- cycle
;
\filldraw[color_208148][nonzero rule]
(203.8743pt, -36.32599pt) -- (460.9143pt, -36.32599pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -36.32599pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -45.68597pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -45.68597pt)
 -- (203.8743pt, -45.68597pt) -- cycle
;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{picture}(-5,0)(2.5,0)
\put(203.8743,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}2)}
\put(210.5384,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}Se}
\put(218.5344,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}c}
\put(222.081,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}o}
\put(226.079,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}nd }
\put(236.9801,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}c}
\put(240.5267,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}o}
\put(244.5247,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}upl}
\put(255.6476,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}e}
\put(259.1941,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(261.1963,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}o}
\put(265.1943,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}f}
\put(267.8618,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(269.864,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}v}
\put(273.862,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}a}
\put(277.86,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}l}
\put(280.084,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}ue}
\put(288.08,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}s}
\put(291.1909,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(293.1931,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}:}
\put(295.8606,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(297.8628,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}W}
\put(305.8604,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}i}
\put(308.0843,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}t}
\put(310.7517,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}h }
\put(317.2102,-43.86957){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}ï¿½}
\put(321.4172,-43.86957){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}?}
\put(323.1829,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}â¡}
\put(329.1596,-43.86957){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}?}
\put(330.925,-43.86957){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}(c?}
\put(339.5428,-43.86957){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}/}
\put(343.4688,-43.86957){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}?}
\put(345.2325,-43.86957){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}d}
\put(349.6733,-43.86957){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791})}
\put(353.0033,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}  }
\put(357.0032,-44.00598){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\end{picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path(0pt,0pt);
\begin{scope}
\clip
(198pt, -93pt) -- (467pt, -93pt)
 -- (467pt, -93pt)
 -- (467pt, 1pt)
 -- (467pt, 1pt)
 -- (198pt, 1pt) -- cycle
;
\filldraw[color_208148][nonzero rule]
(203.8743pt, -45.68597pt) -- (460.9143pt, -45.68597pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -45.68597pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -55.04602pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -55.04602pt)
 -- (203.8743pt, -55.04602pt) -- cycle
;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{picture}(-5,0)(2.5,0)
\put(203.8743,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}3)}
\put(210.5366,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(212.5384,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}In}
\put(220.1035,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}si}
\put(225.4432,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}d}
\put(229.895,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}e }
\put(235.4406,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}ea}
\put(242.99,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}ch}
\put(250.9908,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(252.9874,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}co}
\put(260.5367,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}u}
\put(264.9886,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}p}
\put(269.4404,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}l}
\put(271.6667,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}e }
\put(277.2123,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}o}
\put(281.2127,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}f}
\put(283.8746,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(285.8712,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}v}
\put(289.8716,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}a}
\put(293.872,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}l}
\put(296.0984,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}u}
\put(300.5502,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}es }
\put(309.2091,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}:}
\put(311.871,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(313.8677,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}(}
\put(316.5296,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}a}
\put(320.53,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}1}
\put(324.5304,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(326.527,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}/}
\put(328.7533,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(330.75,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}b}
\put(335.2018,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}1}
\put(339.2022,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791})}
\put(341.8641,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(343.8607,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}=}
\put(348.4235,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(350.4201,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}(}
\put(353.082,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}F}
\put(357.9695,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}o}
\put(361.9698,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}M}
\put(369.5184,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}(}
\put(372.1803,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}1}
\put(376.1807,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}0}
\put(380.1811,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(382.1777,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}b}
\put(386.6296,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}i}
\put(388.8559,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}n}
\put(393.3077,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}s }
\put(398.4177,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791})}
\put(401.0796,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(403.0969,-53.22955){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}/?}
\put(408.7885,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}Fo}
\put(417.6747,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}M}
\put(425.2224,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}(}
\put(427.8836,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}1}
\put(431.8832,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}1}
\put(435.8828,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}bi}
\put(442.5593,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}ns}
\put(450.123,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791})}
\put(452.7884,-53.22955){\fontsize{7.842352}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791})}
\put(456.1126,-53.36603){\fontsize{7.92}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\end{picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path(0pt,0pt);
\begin{scope}
\clip
(198pt, -93pt) -- (467pt, -93pt)
 -- (467pt, -93pt)
 -- (467pt, 1pt)
 -- (467pt, 1pt)
 -- (198pt, 1pt) -- cycle
;
\filldraw[color_208148][nonzero rule]
(203.8743pt, -55.04602pt) -- (460.9143pt, -55.04602pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -55.04602pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -64.16602pt)
 -- (460.9143pt, -64.16602pt)
 -- (203.8743pt, -64.16602pt) -- cycle
;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I can't simply process this kind of source. You could tell to produce the LaTeX myself from scratch but it would be a huge amount of work.

Do you think that commercial products of Aspose are really efficient or other commercial PDF -> LaTeX converter products?

I am working on MacOS Catalina 10.15 and I am looking for a very accurate OCR to produce an easy modifiable LaTeX source (I tried Mathpix too without success). I am ready to pay a commercial product but I don't want an expensive product also.

I have tried `pandoc` but the result is catastrophic in my case.

**UPDATE 2:** I have put online the files PDF and docx in order someone to be able to test the best way to convert the PDF or docx file to Latex source:

[pdf file](http://31.207.36.11/Table_Synthesis_for_SO.pdf)

[docx file](http://31.207.36.11/Table_Synthesis_for_SO.docx)

Any advise/suggestion/help is welcome.

Comment: Your only real option from MS Word is `pandoc`. However, with such heavily formatted table, I guess that it wont do much better. Try it out, if anything, it will give you a good start. Otherwise, I would suggest you to convert it to `.csv` and try to transform that to valid LaTeX syntax.

Comment: When I get a MS Word manuscriptt with tables I first copy and paste them into MS Excel,
then maybe I will make little fixes, like merging rows or columns, and then use the excel2latex plugin.

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex?lang=en

Most of the time I get the final latex table or, in complicated cases, a useful starting point for making corrections.
Since you didn't provide the source document for your table, I can't test the procedure with your example.

Comment: @SimonDispa . Thanks, I have put on line the 2 documents (PDF and docx) on the following links : http://31.207.36.11/Table_Synthesis_for_SO.pdf and http://31.207.36.11/Table_Synthesis_for_SO.docx . Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my answer above to deal with the new table. On the top of the conversion procedure already outlined I added (in the Excel table) blank lines at the top and bottom of each row  to improve the separation between the text and the horizontal lines, I also replaced in the generated code all the p {xx }| columns with l| columns and finally change all  `midline` to `hhline{}`. I didn't touch the original content except for the inclusion of the gamma symbols in some places.

To deal with the white lines getting into colored cells, I used the technique explained by  https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer  in
[hhline and cell color problems revisited](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355974/hhline-and-cell-color-problems-revisited)

I found it much easier to create complicated tables in Excel (not MS Word!) and then export them to LaTeX. The code obtained is much easier to edit to get to the desired final format.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 

\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{hhline}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.6pt}\arrayrulecolor{black}

\usepackage[margin=.2in]{geometry}

\begin{document}    

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \footnotesize  %% added
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
%       \cmidrule{2-4}          
        \hhline{~---} 
        
          \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\multirow{16}[3]{*}{}} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}} \\[-0.5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}
            \textbf{General Output Format :  (a/b) (c/d) [e,f]}} \\[-0.5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}
            \textbf{1) First couple of values : Without  (a / b) } }\\[-0.5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}
            \textbf{2)Second couple of values : With  (c / d)  }} \\[-0.5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}
            \textbf{3) Inside each couple of values : (a1 / b1) = (FoM(10 bins ) / FoM(11bins))}} \\[-0.5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}
            \textbf{4) Inside a couple of values  for GCsp: (a2 / b2) = FoM(4 bins) /FoM(5 bins)}} \\[-0.5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}
        \textbf{5) Standard deviation for each $\gamma$ case (within brackets) : σ on (c,d)  $\gamma$ cases [e, f] = [σc, σd]}} \\[-0.5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}} \\[-0.5pt]
        
%       \cmidrule{2-4}
                \hhline{~---} 
            \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}\\[-0,5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}{\textbf{Pessimistic (IST case):}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}\textbf{Semi - Pessimistic:}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}{\textbf{Optimistic (IST case):}}}\\[-0,5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}kmax = 0.25 h.Mpc-1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}kmax = 0.25 h.Mpc-1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}kmax = 0.3 h.Mpc-1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}lmax(WL) = 1500} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}lmax(WL) = 1500} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}lmax(WL) = 5000}\\[-0,5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}lmax(GCph) = 750} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}lmax(GCph) = 750} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}lmax(GCph) = 3000}\\[-0,5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}lmax(XC) = 750} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}lmax(XC) = 750} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}lmax(XC) = 3000}\\[-0,5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}sig\_p, sig\_v to estimate} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}sig\_p, sig\_v to estimate} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}sig\_p, sig\_v fixed}\\[-0,5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}Zcut for GCsp combined with GCph} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}No Zcut for GCsp combined } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}No Zcut for GCsp combined }\\[-0,5pt]     
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}with GCph } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}with GCph} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}with GCph}\\[-0,5pt]     
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}\\[-0,5pt]
        
%               \cmidrule{2-4}
                        \hhline{----} 
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{GCsp - No $\gamma$  (4/5 bias)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(14.18 / 13.81)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(14.18 / 13.81)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(56.14 / 52.61)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{ GCsp - $\gamma$ (4/5 bias) } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(7.39 / 6.84)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(7.39 / 6.84)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (37.73 / 34.48)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.182 , 0.181]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.182 , 0.181 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.136 , 0.133 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
%       \midrule
        \hhline{----} 
                
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}       &       &       & \\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Pessimistic:}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Semi- Pessimistic case =}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}{\textbf{Optimistic (IST case):}}}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Number of photo bias:}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}{\textbf{Pessimistic (IST case):}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{(No spectro bias here)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Zcut < 0.9}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{No-Zcut}}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{No-Zcut}} & \\[-0,5pt]
        
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
        
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{GCph} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(1.69 / 1.69)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(4.25 / 4.93)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(61.80 / 66.55)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (1.10 / 1.10)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (3.15 / 3.78)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (55.08 / 59.48)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.466 , 0.466 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.429 , 0.409 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.129 , 0.128 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
            %       \midrule
            \hhline{----} 
                
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]   
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{WL} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(24.09 / 25.72)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(24.09 / 25.72)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(46.82 / 50.65)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(7.13 / 8.01)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(7.13 / 8.01)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(13.97 / 15.61)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.191 , 0.180 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.191 , 0.180 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.09 , 0.08 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
        
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{l|}{GCph + WL + XC} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(211.52 / 213.50) } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(358.41 / 382.86)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(1006.13 / 1035.82)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(75.70 / 77.80)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (128.96 / 142.14)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(441.97 / 477.52)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.079 , 0.077 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.062 , 0.058 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.021 , 0.020 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
        
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}       &       &       & \\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} \multicolumn{1}{|l|} {\textbf{Synthesis with simple sum }} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}{Pessimistic (IST case): }} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Semi-Pessimistic case:}} &
         \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}       {\textbf{Optimistic (IST case):}}}\\[-0,5pt]
         \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} \multicolumn{1}{|l|} {\textbf{(GCsp+GCph+WL) and }} & 
         \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &
         \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}   }\\[-0,5pt]          
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} \multicolumn{1}{|l|} {\textbf{GCsp+ (GCph+WL+XC)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{ zcut (5 first bias for GCph)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}}\\[-0,5pt]
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} \multicolumn{1}{|l|} {} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{ zcut < 0.9}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{No-Zcut}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{ \textbf{No-Zcut}}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}       &       &       & \\[-0,5pt]
        
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
        
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{a) Specifications IST :} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}   (121.73 / 125.30)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(151.05 / 156.16)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (351.18 / 367.42) }\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{· (4 bias spectro) : } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (99.81 / 102.38)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(119.72 /127.41)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(262.88 /279.53)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{GCsp + GCph + WL  } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}  [ 0.036, 0.035 ] } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.035 , 0.035 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.018 , 0.017 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
        
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{b) Specifications IST:} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}      (384.80 / 386.64)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(550.01 / 573.48)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(1220.39 / 1249.97) }\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{· (4 bias spectro): } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (255.84 / 257.64 ) } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(320.07 / 333.93)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(692.62 /725.96)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC)  } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.031, 0.031 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.029 , 0.028 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.016 , 0.015 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
        
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{c)  New specifications} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(119.67 / 123.34)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(146.68 / 154.12)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(340.83 / 357.19)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{· Bias independent:} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (99.20 / 101.84 )} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(119.72 / 125.45)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(255.68 / 272.10)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{(5 bias spectro): } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.035, 0.035 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.035 , 0.035 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.018 , 0.017 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{GCsp + GCph + WL  } & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
        
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{d)  New specifications} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(389.00 / 386.80)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(548.22 / 571.35)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(1209.80 / 1235.09)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{· Bias independent :} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (259.32 / 261.08)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(320.84 / 334.05)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(682.82 / 716.27)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{(5 bias spectro) : } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.031, 0.030 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.029 , 0.028 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.016 , 0.015 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC)} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]       
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
        %       \midrule
        \hhline{----} 
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{e)  « common bias » :  ( No $\gamma$) ( $\gamma$) } &
         \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{1}[1]{*}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}{\textbf{Not computable since }}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(781.09) (587.24)} &
          \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(1565.86) (1254.87)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{· 5 Bias dependent :} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{1}[1]{*}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}{\textbf{z\_cut < 0.9}}}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.017 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.009 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC) &   \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}      & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]  
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again, sorry to not be able to reproduce myself this latex source but I am going to work on the method which makes the best rendering compared to other solutions suggested. Regards

Answer (score 3):

Well, this might be so simple a solution that you've already thought of it.

In this answer I'll present several options:

## 1. As close to the original as possible (colors retained, but code messier)

In order to get as close to the original as possible, I would recommend using the following solution:

1. Install LibreOffice and save `Table_Synthesis_for_SO.docx` to `Table_Synthesis_for_SO.odt`.
2. Then go ahead and install Writer2LaTeX from [extensions.libreoffice.org](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/writer2latex-1).
3. Export your document using the following settings (you can and probably should change `US ASCII` to `UTF-8`):
   [image: Writer2LaTeX-Settings]
4. This will create the following document:

```latex
% This file was converted to LaTeX by Writer2LaTeX ver. 1.6.1
% see http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net for more info
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}
\usepackage[noenc]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usepackage[geometry,weather,misc,clock]{ifsym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=2.501cm,bottom=1cm,left=2.501cm,right=2.501cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=}
\providecommand\textsubscript[1]{\ensuremath{{}_{\text{#1}}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother
\raggedbottom
% Paragraph styles
\renewcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}
\newenvironment{stylePxxxiv}{\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}\pagestyle{Standard}
\setlength\leftskip{0cm}\setlength\rightskip{0cm plus 1fil}\setlength\parindent{0cm}\setlength\parfillskip{0pt plus 1fil}\setlength\parskip{0cm plus 1pt}\writerlistparindent\writerlistleftskip\selectlanguage{english}\leavevmode\normalfont\normalsize\normalcolor\writerlistlabel\ignorespaces}{\unskip\vspace{0cm plus 1pt}\par}
% Footnote rule
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.119cm}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.018cm}\setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent\textcolor{black}{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.018cm}}\vspace*{0.101cm}}
% Pages styles
\fancypagestyle{Standard}{\fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{}
  \fancyfoot[L]{}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
  \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
}
\pagestyle{Standard}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
% List styles
\newcommand\writerlistleftskip{}
\newcommand\writerlistparindent{}
\newcommand\writerlistlabel{}
\newcommand\writerlistremovelabel{\aftergroup\let\aftergroup\writerlistparindent\aftergroup\relax\aftergroup\let\aftergroup\writerlistlabel\aftergroup\relax}
\newcommand\liststyleWWNumv{%
\renewcommand\theenumi{\alph{enumi}}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\alph{enumi}.\alph{enumii}}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{\alph{enumii}.\roman{enumiii}}
\renewcommand\theenumiv{\roman{enumiii}.\arabic{enumiv}}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{\theenumii}
\renewcommand\labelenumiii{\theenumiii}
\renewcommand\labelenumiv{\theenumiv}
}
\newcommand\liststyleWWNumvi{%
\renewcommand\labelitemi{[F0B7?]}
\renewcommand\labelitemii{o}
\renewcommand\labelitemiii{[F0A7?]}
\renewcommand\labelitemiv{[F0B7?]}
}
\sloppy
\title{}
\begin{document}
\begin{stylePxxxiv}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\end{stylePxxxiv}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.041cm}
\begin{center}
\tablefirsthead{}
\tablehead{}
\tabletail{}
\tablelasttail{}
\begin{supertabular}{|m{3.307cm}|m{2.915cm}|m{2.9659998cm}|m{2.97cm}|}
\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.7058824,0.9529412}~
 &
\multicolumn{3}{m{9.251cm}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.7058824,0.7764706,0.90588236}~

{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{7.5pt}{9.0pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} General Output Format :  (a/b) (c/d) [e,f]}

~

{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{1) First couple of values : Without }}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{[D835?][DEFE?]}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{ }}} ${\equiv}$ \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{ (a / b) }}}}}

{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{2)Second couple of values : With }}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{[D835?][DEFE?]}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{ }}}} ${\equiv}$ \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{ (c / d)  }}}}}

{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{3) Inside each couple of values : (a1 / b1) = (FoM(10 bins ) / FoM(11bins))}}}}}

{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} 4) Inside a couple of values  for GCsp: (a2 / b2) = FoM(4 bins) /FoM(5 bins)}

{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{5) Standard deviation for each }}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{[D835?][DEFE?]}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{ case~(within brackets) : }}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{$\sigma $}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{ on (c,d)  }}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{[D835?][DEFE?]}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{ cases [e, f] = [}}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{$\sigma $}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{c, }}}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{$\sigma $}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{d}}}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{]}}}}}

~
}\\\hline
 &
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.7058824,0.7764706,0.90588236}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{red} Pessimistic (IST case):\par}

{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{k}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max }}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{= 0.25 h.Mpc}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsuperscript{{}-1}}}}}

{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(WL) = 1500}}}}

{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(GCph) = 750}}}}

{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(XC) = 750}}}}

{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} sig\_p, sig\_v to estimate}

{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} Zcut for GCsp combined with GCph} &
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.7058824,0.7764706,0.90588236}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} Semi - Pessimistic:}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{k}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max }}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{= 0.25 h.Mpc}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsuperscript{{}-1}}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(WL) = 1500}}}

{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(GCph) = 750}}}}

{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(XC) = 750}}}}

{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} sig\_p, sig\_v to estimate}

{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} No Zcut for GCsp combined with GCph} &
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.7058824,0.7764706,0.90588236}{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{red} Optimistic (IST case):}

{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{k}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max }}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{= 0.3 h.Mpc}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsuperscript{{}-1}}}}}

{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(WL) = 5000}}}}

{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(GCph) = 3000}}}}

{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(XC) = 3000}}}}

{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} sig\_p, sig\_v fixed}

{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} No Zcut for GCsp combined with GCph}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.7058824,0.7764706,0.90588236}~

{\centering\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{7.5pt}{9.0pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{GCsp - No }}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{7.5pt}{9.0pt}\selectfont \textit{\textcolor{black}{$\gamma $}}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{7.5pt}{9.0pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{  (4/5 bias)}}}\par}

{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{7.5pt}{9.0pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{ GCsp - }}}{\fontsize{7.5pt}{9.0pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[D835?][DEFE?]}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{7.5pt}{9.0pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{ (4/5 bias) }}}}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (14.18 / 13.81)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (7.39 / 6.84)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.182 , 0.181]\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (14.18 / 13.81)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (7.39 / 6.84)\par}

\centering{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.182 , 0.181 ]} &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (56.14 / 52.61)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black}  (37.73 / 34.48)\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}}} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.136 , 0.133 ]}}}}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.7058824,0.9529412}~

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} Number of photo bias :\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} (No spectro bias here)\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.7058824,0.9529412}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} Pessimistic:\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} (10) / Extended (11)\par}

\centering{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} Zcut {\textless} 0.9} &
\cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.7058824,0.9529412}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} Semi- Pessimistic case =\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{red} Pessimistic (IST case):\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} (10) / Extended (11)\par}

\centering{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} No-Zcut} &
\cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.7058824,0.9529412}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{red} Optimistic (IST case):\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} (10) / Extended (11)\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} No-Zcut}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.7058824,0.7764706,0.90588236}~

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} GCph\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (1.69 / 1.69)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black}  (1.10 / 1.10)\par}

{\centering\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}}} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.466 , 0.466 ]}}}\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (4.25 / 4.93)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black}  (3.15 / 3.78)\par}

\centering{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.429 , 0.409 ]} &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (61.80 / 66.55)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black}  (55.08 / 59.48)\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}}} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.129 , 0.128 ]}}}}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.7058824,0.7764706,0.90588236}\centering{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} WL} &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (24.09 / 25.72)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (7.13 / 8.01)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.191 , 0.180 ]\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (24.09 / 25.72)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (7.13 / 8.01)\par}

\centering{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.191 , 0.180 ]} &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (46.82 / 50.65)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (13.97 / 15.61)\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.09 , 0.08 ]}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.7058824,0.7764706,0.90588236}~

{\centering\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} GCph + WL + XC\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (211.52 / 213.50) \par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (75.70 / 77.80)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.079 , 0.077 ]\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (358.41 / 382.86)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black}  (128.96 / 142.14)\par}

\centering{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}}} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.062 , 0.058 ]}}}} &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (1006.13 / 1035.82)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (441.97 / 477.52)\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.021 , 0.020 ]}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.7058824,0.9529412}~

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} Synthesis with simple sum (GCsp+GCph+WL) and \par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} GCsp+ (GCph+WL+XC)\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.7058824,0.9529412}~

\centering{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{red}{Pessimistic (IST case):  }}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{zcut (5 first bias for GCph) Zcut {\textless} 0.9}}}}} &
\cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.7058824,0.9529412}~

{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} Semi-Pessimistic case:}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} (10) / Extended (11)\par}

\centering{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} No-Zcut} &
\cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.7058824,0.9529412}~

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{red} Optimistic (IST case):\par}

{\centering\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{10) / Extended (11)}}}}\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{black} No-Zcut}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.7058824,0.7764706,0.90588236}\liststyleWWNumv
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} Specifications IST :}
\end{enumerate}
\liststyleWWNumvi
\begin{itemize}
\item {\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (4 bias spectro) : }
\end{itemize}
{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} GCsp + GCph + WL  } &
\cellcolor{white}{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black}  (121.73 / 125.30)}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black}  (99.81 / 102.38)\par}

\centering{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{ [}}} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.036, 0.035 ] }}}} &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (151.05 / 156.16)\par}

{\centering\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (119.72 /127.41)\par}

{\centering\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.035 , 0.035 ]\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black}  (351.18 / 367.42) \par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (262.88 /279.53)\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.018 , 0.017 ]}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.7058824,0.7764706,0.90588236}\liststyleWWNumv
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black}  Specifications IST :}
\end{enumerate}
\liststyleWWNumvi
\begin{itemize}
\item {\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (4 bias spectro) : }
\end{itemize}
{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC)  } &
\cellcolor{white}{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black}  (384.80 / 386.64)}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black}  (255.84 / 257.64 ) \par}

\centering{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}}} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.031, 0.031 ]}}}} &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (550.01 / 573.48)\par}

{\centering\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (320.07 / 333.93)\par}

{\centering\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.029 , 0.028 ]\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (1220.39 / 1249.97) \par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (692.62 /725.96)\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.016 , 0.015 ]}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.7058824,0.7764706,0.90588236}\liststyleWWNumv
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} New specifications}
\end{enumerate}
\liststyleWWNumvi
\begin{itemize}
\item {\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} Bias independent :}
\end{itemize}
{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (5 bias spectro) : }

{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} GCsp + GCph + WL  } &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (119.67 / 123.34)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black}  (99.20 / 101.84 )\par}

\centering{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}}} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.035, }}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.035 ]}}}} &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (146.68 / 154.12)\par}

{\centering\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (119.72 / 125.45)\par}

{\centering\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.035 , 0.035 ]\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (340.83 / 357.19)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (255.68 / 272.10)\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}}} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.018 , 0.017 ]}}}}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.7058824,0.7764706,0.90588236}\liststyleWWNumv
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} New specifications}
\end{enumerate}
\liststyleWWNumvi
\begin{itemize}
\item {\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} Bias independent :}
\end{itemize}
{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (5 bias spectro) : }

{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC)} &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (389.00 / 386.80)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black}  (259.32 / 261.08)\par}

\centering{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.031, 0.030 ]} &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (548.22 / 571.35)\par}

{\centering\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (320.84 / 334.05)\par}

\centering{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.029 , 0.028 ]} &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (1209.80 / 1235.09)\par}

{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (682.82 / 716.27)\par}

{\centering\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}}} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.016 , 0.015 ]}}}\par}

~
\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.7058824,0.7764706,0.90588236}\liststyleWWNumv
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\color{black} \foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{{\guillemotleft}~common bias~{\guillemotright} :  ( }}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{9pt}{10.8pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{No }}}{\fontsize{9pt}{10.8pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[D835?][DEFE?]}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{9pt}{10.8pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{) ( }}}{\fontsize{9pt}{10.8pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[D835?][DEFE?]}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{9pt}{10.8pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{)}}}\foreignlanguage{english}{{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{ }}}}
\end{enumerate}
\liststyleWWNumvi
\begin{itemize}
\item {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} 5 Bias dependent :}
\end{itemize}
{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC)} &
\cellcolor{white}\centering{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\bfseries\color{red} Not computable since z\_cut {\textless} 0.9} &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (781.09) (587.24)\par}

\centering{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.017 ]} &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} (1565.86) (1254.87)\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\selectlanguage{english}\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont\color{black} [ 0.009 ]}\\\hline
\end{supertabular}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I would strongly recommend removing or at least commenting the following lines:

```latex
%\begin{center}
%\begin{minipage}{0.041cm}
%\begin{center}
…
%\end{center}
%\end{minipage}
%\end{center}
```

This will vastly improve the output and give you something like this:

[image: PDF output of Writer2LaTeX]

## 2. Further away from the original (colors lost, but code quite readable)

This is what I would recommend to you. It gives you an excellent base for your own alterations, preserves the table and is actually quite clean codewise.

Here are the necessary settings for Writer2LaTeX:

[image: Ultra-clean Article in Writer2LaTeX]

With all the code samples I'm close to the max. word count available, so I'll have to call it quits here.

## Final remarks

I think, LibreOffice can really help you here, since it produces an actual table. I have also tried pandoc which would produce empty tex and pdf files.

**My recommendation**: Use the Ultra-clean Article and start building from there. If you have trouble guessing the colors or which packages to load, have a look at solution 1 above and use the necessary code from there. The Ultra-clean Article loads less packages, removes all the unnecessary fontsize declarations from Word/LibreOffice and gives you a really nice document.

**Just remember to remove the center and minipage environments and you'll be fine.**

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already had exported your table to .png with enough resolution for medium quality printing, it might be simpler to include it as an image.

```
            \documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
            \RequirePackage{graphicx}
            \usepackage[margin=.9in]{geometry}

            \begin{document}
            \includegraphics[height=\textheight]{9ph4R.png}
            \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this steps:

1. Cut and paste table to ms excel (I am using 2013).
2. Format some rows to make equal to the doc table, remove extra empty rows, etc.
3. Use addin excel2latex to generate the code of a LaTeX table. Insert the code in a LaTeX document with some added packages.
4. Make small changes: replace midrule  by hhline + change font size to fit the table in the page.

This is the resulting code

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 

    \usepackage{colortbl} 
    \usepackage{multirow} 
    \usepackage{hhline}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}\arrayrulecolor{black}

    \usepackage[margin=.2in]{geometry}

    \begin{document}
        
    % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
    \begin{table}[htbp]
            \footnotesize  %% added
        \centering
        \caption{Add caption}
    %   \begin{tabular}{|p{18.215em}|r|p{16.215em}|r|}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{18.215em}|r|p{15.785em}|p{15.785em}|} % changed
    %%      \midrule
    \hhline{~---}  %replace \midrule
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{p{50.5em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}\textbf{General Output Format :  (a/b) (c/d) [e,f]}} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{p{50.5em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}1) First couple of values : Without     (a / b)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{p{50.5em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}\textbf{2)Second couple of values : With                          (c / d)  }} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{p{50.5em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}\textbf{3) Inside each couple of values : (a1 / b1) = (FoM(10 bins ) / FoM(11bins))}} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{p{50.5em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}\textbf{4) Inside a couple of values  for GCsp: (a2 / b2) = FoM(4 bins) /FoM(5 bins)}} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{p{50.5em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}\textbf{5) Standard deviation for each  case (within brackets) : σ on (c,d)   cases [e, f] = [σc, σd]}} \\
            \hhline{~---}     \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{Pessimistic (IST case):}}} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}\textbf{Semi - Pessimistic:} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{Optimistic (IST case):}}} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}kmax = 0.25 h.Mpc-1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}kmax = 0.25 h.Mpc-1 & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}kmax = 0.3 h.Mpc-1} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}lmax(WL) = 1500} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}lmax(WL) = 1500 & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}lmax(WL) = 5000} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}lmax(GCph) = 750} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}lmax(GCph) = 750 & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}lmax(GCph) = 3000} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}lmax(XC) = 750} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}lmax(XC) = 750 & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}lmax(XC) = 3000} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}sig\_p, sig\_v to estimate} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}sig\_p, sig\_v to estimate & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}sig\_p, sig\_v fixed} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}Zcut for GCsp combined with GCph} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}No Zcut for GCsp combined with GCph & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}No Zcut for GCsp combined with GCph} \\
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{~---}  %replace \midrule
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(14.18 / 13.81) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(56.14 / 52.61)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} GCsp - No   (4/5 bias) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(14.18 / 13.81)} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(7.39 / 6.84) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (37.73 / 34.48)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906}             GCsp -  (4/5 bias)  & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(7.39 / 6.84)} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.182 , 0.181 ] & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.136 , 0.133 ]} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.182 , 0.181]} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{~---}  %replace \midrule
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\textbf{Pessimistic:}} & \textbf{Semi- Pessimistic case =} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{Optimistic (IST case):}}} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \textbf{Number of photo bias :} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{Pessimistic (IST case):}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \textbf{(No spectro bias here)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\textbf{Zcut < 0.9}} & \textbf{(10) / Extended (11)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\textbf{No-Zcut}} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &       & \textbf{No-Zcut} &  \\
    %       \midrule
        \hhline{~---}  %replace \midrule
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(61.80 / 66.55)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} GCph  & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(1.69 / 1.69)} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(4.25 / 4.93) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (55.08 / 59.48)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (1.10 / 1.10)} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (3.15 / 3.78) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.129 , 0.128 ]} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.466 , 0.466 ]} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.429 , 0.409 ] & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{~---}  %replace \midrule
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} WL    & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(24.09 / 25.72) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(46.82 / 50.65)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(24.09 / 25.72)} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(7.13 / 8.01) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(13.97 / 15.61)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(7.13 / 8.01)} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.191 , 0.180 ] & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.09 , 0.08 ]} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.191 , 0.180 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{~---}  %replace \midrule
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(1006.13 / 1035.82)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} GCph + WL + XC & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(211.52 / 213.50) } & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(358.41 / 382.86) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(441.97 / 477.52)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(75.70 / 77.80)} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (128.96 / 142.14) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.021 , 0.020 ]} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.079 , 0.077 ]} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.062 , 0.058 ] & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{~---}  %replace \midrule
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} &  \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \textbf{Synthesis with simple sum (GCsp+GCph+WL) and } & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\textbf{Pessimistic (IST case):  zcut (5 first bias for GCph) Zcut < 0.9}} & \textbf{Semi-Pessimistic case:} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{Optimistic (IST case):}}} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \textbf{GCsp+ (GCph+WL+XC)} &       & \textbf{(10) / Extended (11)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{(10) / Extended (11)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .706,  .953} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &       & \textbf{No-Zcut} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\textbf{No-Zcut}} \\
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{~---}  %replace \midrule
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} a)        Specifications IST : & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}       (121.73 / 125.30)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (351.18 / 367.42) } \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} ·          (4 bias spectro) :  & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (99.81 / 102.38)} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(151.05 / 156.16) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(262.88 /279.53)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} GCsp + GCph + WL   & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}  [ 0.036, 0.035 ] } & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(119.72 /127.41) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.018 , 0.017 ]} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.035 , 0.035 ] & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{~---}  %replace \midrule
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} b)         Specifications IST : & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}      (384.80 / 386.64)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(1220.39 / 1249.97) } \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} ·          (4 bias spectro) :  & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (255.84 / 257.64 ) } & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(550.01 / 573.48) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(692.62 /725.96)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC)   & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.031, 0.031 ]} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(320.07 / 333.93) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.016 , 0.015 ]} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.029 , 0.028 ] & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{~---}  %replace \midrule
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} c)        New specifications & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(119.67 / 123.34)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(340.83 / 357.19)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} ·          Bias independent : & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (99.20 / 101.84 )} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(146.68 / 154.12) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(255.68 / 272.10)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} (5 bias spectro) :  & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.035, 0.035 ]} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(119.72 / 125.45) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.018 , 0.017 ]} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} GCsp + GCph + WL   & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.035 , 0.035 ] & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{~---}  %replace \midrule
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} d)        New specifications & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(389.00 / 386.80)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} ·          Bias independent : & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (259.32 / 261.08)} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(548.22 / 571.35) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(1209.80 / 1235.09)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} (5 bias spectro) :  & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.031, 0.030 ]} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(320.84 / 334.05) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(682.82 / 716.27)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC) & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.029 , 0.028 ] & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.016 , 0.015 ]} \\
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{~---}  %replace \midrule
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} e)        « common bias » :       ( No ) ( )  & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{\textbf{Not computable since z\_cut < 0.9}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(1565.86) (1254.87)} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} ·          5 Bias dependent : & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(781.09) (587.24) & \multicolumn{1}{p{15.785em}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.009 ]} \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .706,  .776,  .906} GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC) & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  0,  0}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.017 ] & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} \\
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{~---}  %replace \midrule
        \end{tabular}%
        \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{table}%

    \end{document}
```

While the solution might answer the question (going from word to editable LaTex code) the final result, as it is, is far from satisfactory,  mostly because the white lines that appear in the multirow colored cells.
This is a known problem.
See [Colored tables and cline/hhline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101249/colored-tables-and-cline-hhline)

Perhaps the result would be better if only the color is used to differentiate the  cells.

[image: From Word to LateX]

Comment: Thanks, I have awarded you since I get the best rendering with your method. Regards

Comment: @youpilat13 Thank you. Your puzzle gave me some fun and I learned new things along the way.

Comment: Hi, I would have a favour to ask you. Could you apply the same procedure (I can't manage to do it myself) on the following docx (the differences are that colors are light/dark greay and the cell top-left deleted) : it is available on :  http://31.207.36.11/Table_Synthesis_GREY.docx . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @youpilat13 Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to save the Word file as html and used the following Python script to convert html to LaTeX. It is still different from your original design, but I think you can build from here.

[image: output]

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pylatex import Tabular, MultiColumn, TableRowSizeError, NoEscape

with open('Table_Synthesis_for_SO.htm', 'r') as infile:
    htm_src = infile.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(htm_src, 'html5lib')

table = soup.find('table')

latex_special_chars = {
    '&': r'\&',
    '%': r'\%',
    '$': r'\$',
    '#': r'\#',
    '_': r'\_',
    '{': r'\{',
    '}': r'\}',
    '~': r'\textasciitilde{}',
    '^': r'\^{}',
    '\\': r'\textbackslash{}',
    '-': r'{-}',
    '[': r'{[}',
    ']': r'{]}',
}

def escape_latex(s):

    if isinstance(s, NoEscape):
        return s

    return NoEscape(''.join(latex_special_chars.get(c, c) for c in str(s)))

def extract_text(element):
    res = []
    for p in element.find_all('p'):
        text = escape_char(escape_latex(p.text.strip()))
        if len(text) > 0:
            res.append(text)
    ret = '\\\\ \n'.join(res)
    return '\\makecell{%s}' % ret

def escape_char(s):
    return s.replace('', '$\\gamma$').replace('σ', '$\\sigma$')

tabular = Tabular('m{5cm}' * 4)

trs = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    col = []
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    for td in tds:
        text = NoEscape(extract_text(td))
        colspan = int(td.attrs.get('colspan', '1'))
        if colspan > 1:
            col.append(MultiColumn(colspan, align='c', data=text))
        else:
            col.append(text)
    while True:
        try:
            tabular.add_row(col)
            break
        except TableRowSizeError:
            # manually insert something in second row
            col.insert(0, '')

with open('tb_src.tex', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    print(tabular.dumps())
    outfile.write(tabular.dumps())
```

The resulting TeX source is:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}


\begin{document}

{\tiny

\begin{tabular}{m{5cm}m{5cm}m{5cm}m{5cm}}%
\makecell{}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell{General
  Output Format :  (a/b) (c/d) {[}e,f{]}\\ 
1) First
  couple of values : Without $\gamma$
   (a / b)\\ 
2)Second
  couple of values : With $\gamma$
   (c / d)\\ 
3) Inside
  each couple of values : (a1 / b1) = (FoM(10 bins ) / FoM(11bins))\\ 
4) Inside a
  couple of values  for GCsp: (a2 / b2) = FoM(4 bins) /FoM(5 bins)\\ 
5) Standard deviation for each $\gamma$ case (within brackets) : $\sigma$ on (c,d)  $\gamma$ cases {[}e, f{]} = {[}$\sigma$c, $\sigma$d{]}}}\\%
&\makecell{Pessimistic (IST case):\\ 
kmax = 0.25 h.Mpc{-}1\\ 
lmax(WL) = 1500\\ 
lmax(GCph) = 750\\ 
lmax(XC) = 750\\ 
sig\_p, sig\_v to estimate\\ 
Zcut for GCsp combined with GCph}&\makecell{Semi {-} Pessimistic:\\ 
kmax = 0.25 h.Mpc{-}1\\ 
lmax(WL) = 1500\\ 
lmax(GCph) = 750\\ 
lmax(XC) = 750\\ 
sig\_p, sig\_v to estimate\\ 
No Zcut for GCsp combined with GCph}&\makecell{Optimistic (IST case):\\ 
kmax = 0.3
  h.Mpc{-}1\\ 
lmax(WL) =
  5000\\ 
lmax(GCph) =
  3000\\ 
lmax(XC) =
  3000\\ 
sig\_p, sig\_v fixed\\ 
No Zcut for GCsp
  combined with GCph}\\%
\makecell{GCsp {-} No $\gamma$  (4/5 bias)\\ 
GCsp
  {-} $\gamma$
  (4/5 bias)}&\makecell{(14.18 / 13.81)\\ 
(7.39 / 6.84)\\ 
{[} 0.182 , 0.181{]}}&\makecell{(14.18 / 13.81)\\ 
(7.39 / 6.84)\\ 
{[} 0.182 , 0.181 {]}}&\makecell{(56.14 / 52.61)\\ 
(37.73 / 34.48)\\ 
{[} 0.136 , 0.133 {]}}\\%
\makecell{Number of photo bias :\\ 
(No spectro bias here)}&\makecell{Pessimistic:\\ 
(10) / Extended (11)\\ 
Zcut < 0.9}&\makecell{Semi{-} Pessimistic case =\\ 
Pessimistic (IST case):\\ 
(10) / Extended (11)\\ 
No{-}Zcut}&\makecell{Optimistic (IST case):\\ 
(10) / Extended (11)\\ 
No{-}Zcut}\\%
\makecell{GCph}&\makecell{(1.69 / 1.69)\\ 
(1.10 / 1.10)\\ 
{[} 0.466 , 0.466 {]}}&\makecell{(4.25 / 4.93)\\ 
(3.15 / 3.78)\\ 
{[} 0.429 , 0.409 {]}}&\makecell{(61.80 / 66.55)\\ 
(55.08 / 59.48)\\ 
{[} 0.129 , 0.128 {]}}\\%
\makecell{WL}&\makecell{(24.09 / 25.72)\\ 
(7.13 / 8.01)\\ 
{[} 0.191 , 0.180 {]}}&\makecell{(24.09 / 25.72)\\ 
(7.13 / 8.01)\\ 
{[} 0.191 , 0.180 {]}}&\makecell{(46.82 / 50.65)\\ 
(13.97 / 15.61)\\ 
{[} 0.09 , 0.08 {]}}\\%
\makecell{GCph + WL + XC}&\makecell{(211.52 / 213.50)\\ 
(75.70 / 77.80)\\ 
{[} 0.079 , 0.077 {]}}&\makecell{(358.41 / 382.86)\\ 
(128.96 / 142.14)\\ 
{[} 0.062 , 0.058 {]}}&\makecell{(1006.13 / 1035.82)\\ 
(441.97 / 477.52)\\ 
{[} 0.021 , 0.020 {]}}\\%
\makecell{Synthesis with simple sum (GCsp+GCph+WL) and\\ 
GCsp+ (GCph+WL+XC)}&\makecell{Pessimistic (IST case):  zcut (5 first bias for GCph) Zcut <
  0.9}&\makecell{Semi{-}Pessimistic
  case:\\ 
(10) / Extended (11)\\ 
No{-}Zcut}&\makecell{Optimistic (IST case):\\ 
(10) / Extended (11)\\ 
No{-}Zcut}\\%
\makecell{a)       
  Specifications IST :\\ 
·         
  (4 bias spectro) :\\ 
GCsp + GCph + WL}&\makecell{(121.73 /
  125.30)\\ 
(99.81 / 102.38)\\ 
{[} 0.036, 0.035 {]}}&\makecell{(151.05 / 156.16)\\ 
(119.72 /127.41)\\ 
{[} 0.035 , 0.035 {]}}&\makecell{(351.18 / 367.42)\\ 
(262.88 /279.53)\\ 
{[} 0.018 , 0.017 {]}}\\%
\makecell{b)       
   Specifications IST :\\ 
·         
  (4 bias spectro) :\\ 
GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC)}&\makecell{(384.80 / 386.64)\\ 
(255.84 / 257.64 )\\ 
{[} 0.031, 0.031 {]}}&\makecell{(550.01 / 573.48)\\ 
(320.07 / 333.93)\\ 
{[} 0.029 , 0.028 {]}}&\makecell{(1220.39 / 1249.97)\\ 
(692.62 /725.96)\\ 
{[} 0.016 , 0.015 {]}}\\%
\makecell{c)       
  New specifications\\ 
·         
  Bias independent :\\ 
(5 bias spectro) :\\ 
GCsp + GCph + WL}&\makecell{(119.67 / 123.34)\\ 
(99.20 / 101.84 )\\ 
{[} 0.035, 0.035 {]}}&\makecell{(146.68 / 154.12)\\ 
(119.72 / 125.45)\\ 
{[} 0.035 , 0.035 {]}}&\makecell{(340.83 / 357.19)\\ 
(255.68 / 272.10)\\ 
{[} 0.018 , 0.017 {]}}\\%
\makecell{d)       
  New specifications\\ 
·         
  Bias independent :\\ 
(5 bias spectro) :\\ 
GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC)}&\makecell{(389.00 / 386.80)\\ 
(259.32 / 261.08)\\ 
{[} 0.031, 0.030 {]}}&\makecell{(548.22 / 571.35)\\ 
(320.84 / 334.05)\\ 
{[} 0.029 , 0.028 {]}}&\makecell{(1209.80 / 1235.09)\\ 
(682.82 / 716.27)\\ 
{[} 0.016 , 0.015 {]}}\\%
\makecell{e)       
  « common
  bias » :       ( No $\gamma$) ( $\gamma$)\\ 
·         
  5 Bias
  dependent :\\ 
GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC)}&\makecell{Not computable since z\_cut < 0.9}&\makecell{(781.09) (587.24)\\ 
{[} 0.017 {]}}&\makecell{(1565.86) (1254.87)\\ 
{[} 0.009 {]}}\\%
\end{tabular}

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible, from your python script, to add Latex borders for each cell and extern edges of big array ? Regards

Comment: This would make the rendering more readable.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Considered is @youpilat13 comment.

It might be worth to rewrite your table in LaTeX from scratch. For example first few rows can be formatted as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline,
            multirow,
            tabularx}               % new

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{linegoal}               % new

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.6pt}\arrayrulecolor{black}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}               % new
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Add caption}
\label{tab:addlabel}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\columncolor[rgb]{.682, .667, .667}\bfseries}L|
                             *{3}{L|} }
    \hhline{~|---|}
    \rowcolor[rgb]{.682, .667, .667}
\multicolumn{1}{X|}{\cellcolor{white}}
    &   \multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr3\hsize/4-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}%%
        {\bfseries
         General Output Format:  (a / b) (c / d) [e, f]
         \begin{enumerate}[nosep,
                          leftmargin=*,
                          label=\textbullet,
                          before=\vspace{1ex},
                          after=\vspace{-1ex},
                          ]
        \item   First couple of values: Without $\gamma$: (a / b)
        \item   Second couple of values: With $\gamma$: (c / d)
        \item   Inside each couple of values: (a1/b1) = (FoM(10 bins) / FoM(11bins))
        \item   Inside a couple of values  for GCsp: (a2 / b2) = FoM(4 bins) / FoM(5 bins)
        \item   Standard deviation for each $\gamma$ case (within brackets): $\sigma$ on (c,d)  $\gamma$ cases [e, f] = [$\sigma_{\mathrm{c}}, \sigma_{\mathrm{d}}$]
        \end{enumerate}
        }
     \\   \hhline{~|---|}
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816, .808, .808}
\multicolumn{1}{X|}{\cellcolor{white}}
    &   \textcolor[rgb]{ .267, .447, .769}{\textbf{Pessimistic (IST case):}}\newline
        $k_{\max} = 0.25\,\text{h.Mpc}-1$\newline
        $l_{\max}(WL) = 1500$\newline
        $l_{\max}(GCph) = 750$\newline
        $l_{\max}(XC) = 750$\newline
        $\sigma_{\mathrm{p}}, \sigma_{\mathrm{v}}$ to estimate $Z_{\mathrm{cut}}$ for GCsp combined with GCph
        &   \textbf{Semi - Pessimistic:}\newline
            $k_{\max} = 0.25\,\text{h.Mpc}-1$\newline
            $l_{\max}(WL) = 1500$\newline
            $l_{\max}(GCph) = 750$\newline
            $l_{\max}(XC) = 750$\newline
            $\sigma_{\mathrm{p}}, \sigma_{\mathrm{v}}$ to estimate No-$Z_{\mathrm{cut}}$ for GCsp combined with GCph
            &   \textcolor[rgb]{.267, .447, .769}{\textbf{Optimistic (IST case):}}\newline
                $k_{\max} = 0.3\,\text{h.Mpc}-1$\newline
                $l_{\max}(WL) = 1500$\newline
                $l_{\max}(GCph) = 3000$\newline
                $l_{\max}(XC) = 3000$\newline
                $\sigma_{\mathrm{p}}, \sigma_{\mathrm{v}}$ fixed Non-$Z_{\mathrm{cut}}$ for GCsp combined with GCph
    \\ \hhline{|----|}
GCsp - No $\gamma$  (4/5 bias)
        &   (14.18 / 13.81)
            &   (14.18 / 13.81)
                &   (56.14 / 52.61)
    \\ \hhline{|----|}
\multirow{2}{=}{GCsp - $\gamma$ (4/5 bias)}
    &   (7.39 / 6.84)\newline
        [ 0.182, 0.181]
        &   (7.39 / 6.84)\newline
            [ 0.182, 0.181 ]
            &   (37.73 / 34.48)\newline
                [ 0.136 , 0.133 ]
    \\ \hhline{|----|}

\rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}
Pessimistic:
    &   \textbf{Semi- Pessimistic case}
        &   \textcolor[rgb]{.267, .447, .769}{\textbf{(Optimistic IST case):}}
            &   \textcolor[rgb]{.267, .447, .769}{\textbf{Pessimistic (IST case):}}
    \\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{.816, .808, .808}
Number of photo bias:
    &   \textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}
        &   \textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}
            &   \textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}
    \\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{.816, .808, .808}
(No spectro bias here), $\textbf{No-Z}_{\textbf{cut}}$
    &   $\mathbf{Z}_{\mathbf{cut}} < 0.9$
        &   \textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}
            &   \textbf{No-Z}$_{\textbf{cut}}$
    \\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}
        \hhline{|----|}
\end{tabularx}%
    \end{table}%
\end{document}
```

which gives:

I'm sorry but temporary `imgur` doesn't work :-(

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

As you can see, the table code is quite shorter and clear. It has no clutter with `\multcolumn` cells, coloring individual cells etc.

Comment: .You're right,  the rendering is better and easier to modify. By the way, just a question : how to center vertically and horizontally the couple of values inside white box or more generally the content into a box given ? and just vertically for the case  `GCsp + gamma (4/5) bins`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @youpilat13, insert it in `\multirow` cell. See edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can also export a selection of a word document to pdf. After export, you need to crop the resulting pdf with pdfcrop or epspdf (command-line) or epspdftk (gui).