# Procedure to produce a Latex source modifable Latex file from initially a MS Word table

Tags: tables, pdftex, arrays, cellcolor, convert

Sorry to post again from the same subject I posted a few days ago. I have had an answer but impossible to reproduce the generation of a Latex source from a docx MS Word document.

So, I attempt here on tex.stackexchange to better understand how I have to proceed.

The new MS Word table is available here : [new MS Word table docx](http://31.207.36.11/Table_Synthesis_GREY.docx)

Given the fact I didn't manage to follow the procedure given by `@Simon Dispa`, I tried different online converters (docx --> Latex file) but the result is pretty ugly.

I know that I won't be able to get a "perfect" Latex source that gives exactly the same results than Word docx file but I would like to get a Latex source easily modifiable in order to be closed as much as possible than the original MS Word table.

`@Simon Dispa` : if you read this message, could you explain me again more accurately how did you process the first table that I gave to you (i.e, on the first post [first MS word processed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555235/automatic-generation-of-table-made-initially-on-ms-word)) ?

Any help is welcome !

Comment: To be honest, I have never seen an auto-generated latex table code that did not need at least some manual adjustments. This is especially true for more complex tables or highly formatted ones. Why not start with one of the not so pretty tables and modify and improve the code in order to suit your needs?

Comment: I find it rather strange that you've awarded the bounty for your original question to an answer you cannot reproduce yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only repeat myself, since it's so easy: Use writer2latex.

What good is a solution you cannot apply yourself? I understand that the LibreOffice approach leaves much to be desired. But a couple of simple tweaks will make the outcome more pleasant and you can repeat the procedure and tweak settings as often as you like.

For this example I've saved the document as .odt, then cut (`ctrl-x`ed) the entire table and pasted it back in. This way the table respected the page margins and the output (see below) has become a lot better. Try it, the solution is so simple you won't fail reproducing it.

Writer2LaTeX will give you the following code:

```latex
% This file was converted to LaTeX by Writer2LaTeX ver. 1.6.1
% see http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net for more info
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[noenc]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usepackage[geometry,weather,misc,clock]{ifsym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage[LGR,T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,french]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=1.499cm,bottom=0.499cm,left=1.499cm,right=1.499cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=}
\providecommand\textsubscript[1]{\ensuremath{{}_{\text{#1}}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother
\raggedbottom
% Paragraph styles
\renewcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}
% Footnote rule
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.119cm}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.018cm}\setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent\textcolor{black}{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.018cm}}\vspace*{0.101cm}}
% Pages styles
\fancypagestyle{Standard}{\fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{}
  \fancyfoot[L]{}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
  \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
}
\pagestyle{Standard}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
% List styles
\newcommand\writerlistleftskip{}
\newcommand\writerlistparindent{}
\newcommand\writerlistlabel{}
\newcommand\writerlistremovelabel{\aftergroup\let\aftergroup\writerlistparindent\aftergroup\relax\aftergroup\let\aftergroup\writerlistlabel\aftergroup\relax}
\newcommand\liststyleWWNumv{%
\renewcommand\theenumi{\alph{enumi}}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\alph{enumi}.\alph{enumii}}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{\alph{enumii}.\roman{enumiii}}
\renewcommand\theenumiv{\roman{enumiii}.\arabic{enumiv}}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{\theenumii}
\renewcommand\labelenumiii{\theenumiii}
\renewcommand\labelenumiv{\theenumiv}
}
\newcommand\liststyleWWNumvi{%
\renewcommand\labelitemi{[F0B7?]}
\renewcommand\labelitemii{o}
\renewcommand\labelitemiii{[F0A7?]}
\renewcommand\labelitemiv{[F0B7?]}
}
\sloppy
\title{}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tablefirsthead{}
\tablehead{}
\tabletail{}
\tablelasttail{}
\begin{supertabular}{|m{4.6720004cm}|m{4.129cm}|m{4.201cm}|m{4.203cm}|}
\hhline{~---}
\multicolumn{1}{m{4.6720004cm}|}{\cellcolor{white}~
} &
\multicolumn{3}{m{12.933cm}|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.68235296,0.6666667,0.6666667}~

{\color{black} {\fontsize{7.5pt}{9.0pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{General Output Format : \ (a/b) (c/d) [e,f]}}}}

~

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{1) First couple of values : Without [D835?][DEFE?]}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{ }} ${\equiv}$ {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{\ (a / b) }}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{2)Second couple of values : With [D835?][DEFE?] }}} ${\equiv}$ {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{\ (c / d) \ }}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{3) Inside each couple of values : (a1 / b1) = (FoM(10 bins ) / FoM(11bins))}}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{4) Inside a couple of values \ for GCsp: (a2 / b2) = FoM(4 bins) /FoM(5 bins)}}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{5) Standard deviation for each [D835?][DEFE?] case~(within brackets) : \textgreek{s} on (c,d) \ [D835?][DEFE?] cases [e, f] = [\textgreek{s}}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{c, }}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{\textgreek{s}}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{d}}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{]}}}}

~
}\\\hhline{~---}
 &
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.8156863,0.80784315,0.80784315}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0.26666668,0.44705883,0.76862746}{Pessimistic (IST case):}}}\par}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{k}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max }}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{= 0.25 h.Mpc}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsuperscript{{}-1}}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(WL) = 1500}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(GCph) = 750}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(XC) = 750}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{sig\_p, sig\_v to estimate}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{Zcut for GCsp combined with GCph}}} &
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.8156863,0.80784315,0.80784315}{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{Semi - Pessimistic:}}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{k}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max }}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{= 0.25 h.Mpc}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsuperscript{{}-1}}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(WL) = 1500}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(GCph) = 750}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(XC) = 750}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{sig\_p, sig\_v to estimate}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{No Zcut for GCsp combined with GCph}}} &
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.8156863,0.80784315,0.80784315}{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0.26666668,0.44705883,0.76862746}{Optimistic (IST case):}}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{k}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max }}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{= 0.3 h.Mpc}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsuperscript{{}-1}}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(WL) = 5000}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(GCph) = 3000}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{l}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\textsubscript{max}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(XC) = 3000}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{sig\_p, sig\_v fixed}}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{No Zcut for GCsp combined with GCph}}}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.68235296,0.6666667,0.6666667}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{7.5pt}{9.0pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{GCsp - No [D835?][DEFE?] \ (4/5 bias)}}\par}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{7.5pt}{9.0pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ GCsp - [D835?][DEFE?] (4/5 bias) }}}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(14.18 / 13.81)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(7.39 / 6.84)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.182 , 0.181]}}\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(14.18 / 13.81)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(7.39 / 6.84)}}\par}

\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.182 , 0.181 ]}}} &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(56.14 / 52.61)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\ (37.73 / 34.48)}}\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.136 , 0.133 ]}}}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.8156863,0.80784315,0.80784315}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{Number of photo bias :}}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{(No spectro bias here)}}}\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.8156863,0.80784315,0.80784315}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{Pessimistic:}}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{(10) / Extended (11)}}}\par}

\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{Zcut {\textless} 0.9}}}} &
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.8156863,0.80784315,0.80784315}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{Semi- Pessimistic case =}}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0.26666668,0.44705883,0.76862746}{Pessimistic (IST case):}}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{(10) / Extended (11)}}}\par}

\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{No-Zcut}}}} &
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.8156863,0.80784315,0.80784315}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0.26666668,0.44705883,0.76862746}{Optimistic (IST case):}}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{(10) / Extended (11)}}}\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{No-Zcut}}}}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.68235296,0.6666667,0.6666667}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{GCph}}\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(1.69 / 1.69)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\ (1.10 / 1.10)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.466 , 0.466 ]}}\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(4.25 / 4.93)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\ (3.15 / 3.78)}}\par}

\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.429 , 0.409 ]}}} &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(61.80 / 66.55)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\ (55.08 / 59.48)}}\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.129 , 0.128 ]}}}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.68235296,0.6666667,0.6666667}\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{WL}}} &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(24.09 / 25.72)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(7.13 / 8.01)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.191 , 0.180 ]}}\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(24.09 / 25.72)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(7.13 / 8.01)}}\par}

\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.191 , 0.180 ]}}} &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(46.82 / 50.65)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(13.97 / 15.61)}}\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.09 , 0.08 ]}}}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.68235296,0.6666667,0.6666667}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{GCph + WL + XC}}\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(211.52 / 213.50) }}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(75.70 / 77.80)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.079 , 0.077 ]}}\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(358.41 / 382.86)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\ (128.96 / 142.14)}}\par}

\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.062 , 0.058 ]}}} &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(1006.13 / 1035.82)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(441.97 / 477.52)}}\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.021 , 0.020 ]}}}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.8156863,0.80784315,0.80784315}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{Synthesis with simple sum (GCsp+GCph+WL) and }}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{GCsp+ (GCph+WL+XC)}}}\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.8156863,0.80784315,0.80784315}~

\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0.26666668,0.44705883,0.76862746}{Pessimistic (IST case):}}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor[rgb]{0.26666668,0.44705883,0.76862746}{ \ }}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{zcut (5 first bias for GCph) Zcut {\textless} 0.9}}}} &
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.8156863,0.80784315,0.80784315}~

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{Semi-Pessimistic case:}}}}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{(10) / Extended (11)}}}\par}

\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{No-Zcut}}}} &
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.8156863,0.80784315,0.80784315}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0.26666668,0.44705883,0.76862746}{Optimistic (IST case):}}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{10) / Extended (11)}}}\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor{black}{No-Zcut}}}}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.68235296,0.6666667,0.6666667}\liststyleWWNumv
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{Specifications IST :}}}
\end{enumerate}
\liststyleWWNumvi
\begin{itemize}
\item {\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(4 bias spectro) : }}}
\end{itemize}
{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{GCsp + GCph + WL \ }}} &
\cellcolor{white}{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (121.73 / 125.30)}}}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\ (99.81 / 102.38)}}\par}

\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\ \ [}} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.036, 0.035 ] }}} &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(151.05 / 156.16)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(119.72 /127.41)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.035 , 0.035 ]}}\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\ (351.18 / 367.42) }}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(262.88 /279.53)}}\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.018 , 0.017 ]}}}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.68235296,0.6666667,0.6666667}\liststyleWWNumv
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\ Specifications IST :}}}
\end{enumerate}
\liststyleWWNumvi
\begin{itemize}
\item {\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(4 bias spectro) : }}}
\end{itemize}
{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC) \ }}} &
\cellcolor{white}{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\ \ \ \ \ \ (384.80 / 386.64)}}}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\ (255.84 / 257.64 ) }}\par}

\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.031, 0.031 ]}}} &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(550.01 / 573.48)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(320.07 / 333.93)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.029 , 0.028 ]}}\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(1220.39 / 1249.97) }}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(692.62 /725.96)}}\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.016 , 0.015 ]}}}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.68235296,0.6666667,0.6666667}\liststyleWWNumv
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{New specifications}}}
\end{enumerate}
\liststyleWWNumvi
\begin{itemize}
\item {\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{Bias independent :}}}
\end{itemize}
{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(5 bias spectro) : }}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{GCsp + GCph + WL \ }}} &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(119.67 / 123.34)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\ (99.20 / 101.84 )}}\par}

\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.035, 0.035 ]}}} &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(146.68 / 154.12)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(119.72 / 125.45)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.035 , 0.035 ]}}\par}

~
 &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(340.83 / 357.19)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(255.68 / 272.10)}}\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.018 , 0.017 ]}}}\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.68235296,0.6666667,0.6666667}\liststyleWWNumv
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{New specifications}}}
\end{enumerate}
\liststyleWWNumvi
\begin{itemize}
\item {\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{Bias independent :}}}
\end{itemize}
{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(5 bias spectro) : }}}

{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC)}}} &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(389.00 / 386.80)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{\ (259.32 / 261.08)}}\par}

\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.031, 0.030 ]}}} &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(548.22 / 571.35)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(320.84 / 334.05)}}\par}

\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.029 , 0.028 ]}}} &
\cellcolor{white}~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(1209.80 / 1235.09)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(682.82 / 716.27)}}\par}

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[}} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{0.016 , 0.015 ]}}\par}

~
\\\hline
\cellcolor[rgb]{0.68235296,0.6666667,0.6666667}\liststyleWWNumv
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{«~common bias~» : \ \ \ \ \ \ ( }}{\fontsize{9pt}{10.8pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{No [D835?][DEFE?]) ( [D835?][DEFE?])}}{\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{ }}}
\end{enumerate}
\liststyleWWNumvi
\begin{itemize}
\item {\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{5 Bias dependent :}}}
\end{itemize}
{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC)}}} &
\cellcolor{white}\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0.26666668,0.44705883,0.76862746}{Not computable since z\_cut {\textless} 0.9}}}} &
\cellcolor{white}~

~

{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(781.09) (587.24)}}\par}

\centering{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.017 ]}}} &
\cellcolor{white}{\centering\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{(1565.86) (1254.87)}}\par}

\centering\arraybslash{\color{black} {\fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont \textcolor{black}{[ 0.009 ]}}}\\\hline
\end{supertabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And the output looks like this:

[image: Table conversion with Writer2LaTeX]