# Issue with the rendering of a Latex table generated from Excel

Tags: tables, pdftex, multicolumn, border

I make follow from the following post :

[Automatic generation of table made initially on MS word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555235/automatic-generation-of-table-made-initially-on-ms-word)

The solution that produces the best rendering and the more easily modifiable is giving by `@Simon Dispa`.

I didn't see at first sight but there are 2 little issues appearing in the final table compiled with `pdflatex` on MacOS. Indeed, the result is :

[image: image with indications]

I mark in red the 2 issues :

1. on the left, you can see that on the left border vertical straight line, a part of vertical line is missing.
2. On bottom, the index in "Z_cut", i.e the index "cut" **is itself cutted on the bottom** : a part of this index is masked and I don't understand why.

**I put below the entire Latex source in order to see if these little problems can be solved by fixing the source.**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 

\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{hhline}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.6pt}\arrayrulecolor{black}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage[margin=.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}    

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \footnotesize  %% added
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
%       \cmidrule{2-4}          
        \hhline{~---} 
        
          \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\multirow{16}[3]{*}{}} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}} \\[-0.5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}
            \textbf{General Output Format :  (a / b) (c / d) [e, f]}} \\[-0.5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}
            \textbf{1) First couple of values : Without $\gamma$ : (a / b) } }\\[-0.5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}
            \textbf{2) Second couple of values : With $\gamma$ : (c / d)  }} \\[-0.5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}
            \textbf{3) Inside each couple of values : (a1/b1) = (FoM(10 bins) / FoM(11bins))}} \\[-0.5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}
            \textbf{4) Inside a couple of values  for GCsp: (a2 / b2) = FoM(4 bins) /FoM(5 bins)}} \\[-0.5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}
        \textbf{5) Standard deviation for each $\gamma$ case (within brackets) : $\sigma$ on (c,d)  $\gamma$ cases [e, f] = [$\sigma_{\text{c}}$, $\sigma_{\text{d}}$]}} \\[0.5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}} \\[-0.5pt]
        
%       \cmidrule{2-4}
                \hhline{~---} 
            \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}\\[-0,5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}{\textbf{Pessimistic (IST case):}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}\textbf{Semi - Pessimistic:}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}{\textbf{Optimistic (IST case):}}}\\[-0,5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$k_{\text{max}}$ = 0.25 h.Mpc-1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$k_{\text{max}}$ = 0.25 h.Mpc-1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$k_{\text{max}}$ = 0.3 h.Mpc-1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$l_{\text{max}}$(WL) = 1500} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$l_{\text{max}}$(WL) = 1500} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$l_{\text{max}}$(WL) = 5000}\\[-0,5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$l_{\text{max}}$(GCph) = 750} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$l_{\text{max}}$(GCph) = 750} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$l_{\text{max}}$(GCph) = 3000}\\[-0,5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$l_{\text{max}}$(XC) = 750} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$l_{\text{max}}$(XC) = 750} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$l_{\text{max}}$(XC) = 3000}\\[-0,5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$\sigma_{\text{p}}$, $\sigma_{\text{v}}$ to estimate} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$\sigma_{\text{p}}$, $\sigma_{\text{v}}$ to estimate} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$\sigma_{\text{p}}$, $\sigma_{\text{v}}$ fixed}\\[-0,5pt]
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}$Z_{\text{cut}}$ for GCsp combined with GCph} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}No-\text{Z}$_{\text{cut}}$ for GCsp combined } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}No-\text{Z}$_{\text{cut}}$ for GCsp combined }\\[-0,5pt]     
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}with GCph } & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}with GCph} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}with GCph}\\[-0,5pt]     
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}\\[-0,5pt]
        
%               \cmidrule{2-4}
                        \hhline{----} 
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{GCsp - No $\gamma$  (4/5 bias)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(14.18 / 13.81)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(14.18 / 13.81)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(56.14 / 52.61)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{ GCsp - $\gamma$ (4/5 bias) } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(7.39 / 6.84)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(7.39 / 6.84)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (37.73 / 34.48)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.182 , 0.181]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.182 , 0.181 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.136 , 0.133 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
%       \midrule
        \hhline{----} 
                
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}       &       &       & \\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Pessimistic:}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Semi- Pessimistic case}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}{\textbf{(Optimistic IST case):}}}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Number of photo bias:}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}{\textbf{Pessimistic (IST case):}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{(No spectro bias here)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\textbf{Z}_{\textbf{cut}} \textbf{< 0.9}$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{No-Z}$_{\textbf{cut}}$}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\textbf{No-Z}_{\textbf{cut}}$} & \\[-0,5pt]
        
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
        
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{GCph} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(1.69 / 1.69)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(4.25 / 4.93)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(61.80 / 66.55)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (1.10 / 1.10)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (3.15 / 3.78)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (55.08 / 59.48)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.466 , 0.466 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.429 , 0.409 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.129 , 0.128 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
            %       \midrule
            \hhline{----} 
                
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]   
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{WL} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(24.09 / 25.72)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(24.09 / 25.72)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(46.82 / 50.65)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(7.13 / 8.01)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(7.13 / 8.01)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(13.97 / 15.61)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.191 , 0.180 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.191 , 0.180 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.09 , 0.08 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
        
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{l|}{GCph + WL + XC} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(211.52 / 213.50) } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(358.41 / 382.86)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(1006.13 / 1035.82)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(75.70 / 77.80)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (128.96 / 142.14)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(441.97 / 477.52)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.079 , 0.077 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.062 , 0.058 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.021 , 0.020 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
        
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}       &       &       & \\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} \multicolumn{1}{|l|} {\textbf{Synthesis with simple sum }} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}{\textbf{Pessimistic (IST case): }}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Semi-Pessimistic case:}} &
         \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}       {\textbf{Optimistic (IST case):}}}\\[-0,5pt]
         \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} \multicolumn{1}{|l|} {\textbf{(GCsp+GCph+WL) and }} & 
         \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &
         \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}   }\\[-0,5pt]          
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} \multicolumn{1}{|l|} {\textbf{GCsp+ (GCph+WL+XC)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Z}$_{\textbf{cut}}$ \textbf{(5 first bias for GCph)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{(10) / Extended (11)}}\\[-0,5pt]
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808} \multicolumn{1}{|l|} {} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Z}$_{\textbf{cut}}$ \textbf{< 0.9}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{No-Z}$_{\textbf{cut}}$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{No-Z}$_{\textbf{cut}}$}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .816,  .808,  .808}       &       &       & \\[-0,5pt]
        
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
        
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{a) Specifications IST :} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}   (121.73 / 125.30)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(151.05 / 156.16)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (351.18 / 367.42) }\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$\bullet$ (4 bias spectro) : } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (99.81 / 102.38)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(119.72 /127.41)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(262.88 /279.53)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{GCsp + GCph + WL  } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}  [ 0.036, 0.035 ] } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.035 , 0.035 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.018 , 0.017 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
        
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{b) Specifications IST:} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}      (384.80 / 386.64)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(550.01 / 573.48)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(1220.39 / 1249.97) }\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$\bullet$ (4 bias spectro): } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (255.84 / 257.64 ) } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(320.07 / 333.93)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(692.62 /725.96)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC)  } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.031, 0.031 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.029 , 0.028 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.016 , 0.015 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
        
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{c)  New specifications} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(119.67 / 123.34)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(146.68 / 154.12)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(340.83 / 357.19)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$\bullet$ Bias independent:} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (99.20 / 101.84 )} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(119.72 / 125.45)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(255.68 / 272.10)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{(5 bias spectro): } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.035, 0.035 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.035 , 0.035 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.018 , 0.017 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{GCsp + GCph + WL  } & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
        
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{d)  New specifications} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(389.00 / 386.80)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(548.22 / 571.35)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(1209.80 / 1235.09)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$\bullet$  Bias independent :} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} (259.32 / 261.08)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(320.84 / 334.05)} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(682.82 / 716.27)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{(5 bias spectro) : } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.031, 0.030 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.029 , 0.028 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.016 , 0.015 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC)} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]       
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        
        %       \midrule
        \hhline{----} 
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{e)  Â« common bias Â» :  ( No $\gamma$) ( $\gamma$) } &
         \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{1}[1]{*}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}{\textbf{Not computable since }}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(781.09) (587.24)} &
          \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}(1565.86) (1254.87)}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$\bullet$ 5 Bias dependent :} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{1}[1]{*}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}{\textbf{Z$_{\textbf{cut}}$ < 0.9}}}}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.017 ]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}[ 0.009 ]}\\[-0,5pt]
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667} GCsp + (GCph + WL + XC) &   \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}      & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]  
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}\\[-0,5pt]
    %       \midrule
    \hhline{----} 
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Any suggestion or clue is welcome.

Comment: please see the edit to the answer below also for the Z_cut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You missed out the left column strut below

```
 \multicolumn{1}{l|} {\textbf{GCsp+ (GCph+WL+XC)}}
```

change it to

```
 \multicolumn{1}{|l|} {\textbf{GCsp+ (GCph+WL+XC)}}
```

for the z_cut change the multirow to

```
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{0.5}[1]{*}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  
1}\textcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .447,  .769}{\textbf{Z$_{\textbf{cut}}$
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I would like to have the same foresight than you.